# How to prevent reassignment of variable to object of same class from keeping previous data?

Tags: python, class, default-value, keyword-argument

When reassigning box with a new instance of `Box`, instead of `self.things` being assigned an empty dictionary, it contains the same data from the previous instance.

I'm using python 3.7.3

```py
import random

class Box:
    def __init__(self, things = {}):
        self.things = things

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.things)

    def put_thing_in_location(self, thing, location):
        self.things[location] = thing


for i in range(2):
    box = Box()
    print(box)
    box.put_thing_in_location(
        random.randrange(10000), 
        random.randrange(10000)
    )
```

Output:

```
$ python bugTest.py

{}

{652: 8968}
```

I expect that `things` of the new instance of `Box` be an empty dictionary if no arguments are passed to it.
Instead it keeps `things` from the previous instance of `Box`.

Comment: Do you mean to print `box` before you put the numbers in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning the exact same dictionary as the default to your instances, thus **sharing** it across all instances.  Change your constructor to

```
def __init__(self, things=None):
    self.things = {} if things is None else things
```

This ensures that each instance takes a fresh dictionary as the default if nothing is given.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the function `def __init__(self, things = {}):`, `things` gets initialized to an empty dict and whenever `__init__` gets invoked, the same dict (which might not be empty when you invoke it second time) would be passed, when you dont explicitly specify an value for `things`

```
def __init__(self, things = None):
     things = things or {}
     ...
```

Comment: The only (very marginal) disadvantage of using the `things or {}` approach is that if the caller explicitly provides an empty dictionary that they expect to become the `things` attribute, they don’t get that empty dictionary as the attribute.